# When seeking a reference, is it better to ask a workmate you work closely with, or the most senior person in your team?

Tags: software-industry, internship, references

I'm about to finish an internship and am starting a search for a new job. I am on a small team, and I am trying to choose from among two people to ask for a reference: my workmate, or the team lead. My workmate is the person who sees my code and assists me in learning more often, so I know that he can speak about my growth. He also likes me, so I am sure he would provide a good positive character reference as well as a work reference. He's a senior, so I believe his reference will carry enough weight.

Or, I could ask the lead, who is more senior (so I am assuming his reference will carry even more weight?). However, as he has many meetings with stakeholders and other teams, he does not see as much of my work, so he would not be able to talk as in depth. Which reference would be better for when I am in the interview stage of future jobs?

Comment: Why not ask both for references? It's not an either/or scenario.

Answer (score 5):

I really don't see a reason to not ask both people for references. Two is better than one after all.

Obviously the more senior the title of the person writing the reference, the better it looks. But as they say, quantity has a quality all on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the workmate who is sure to give a glowing review and can be prompted to help you "connect the dots" from the new job description to your work experience. I would imagine it would be harder to get your boss to really push for you like that. A personalized enthusiastic endorsement will reflect a lot better on you than a boss that can't provide a lot of details about you.

The search committees I've participated in don't place a lot of credence in reference titles. We're *much* more interested in "*is x a good match for us?*" than "*have you heard good things about x?*".

To wit, while we would ask "who was your boss, and may we contact them?", I've never actually called a boss; we focused on the professional references. The only time I've seen a personal or supervisor reference called was for a rather young (but highly skilled) candidate we wanted to make sure was mature enough for a potentially-sensitive position.

In short, from a search perspective, don't try to impress with titles, give us something we can use!

Answer (score 0):

## Probably both yet possibly neither.

### Firstly, there are two aspects to references:

Asking someone if they would be willing to be a reference in the future, and 'confirming' this willingness with them before you actually provide that person's contact details to a prospective employer of yours.

Asking someone if they'd be willing to act as a reference for you in the future is the first step, you generally do this in the last few days before your employment at a particular job/project ends. It's as simple as asking something like:

> Hey X, I was wondering, if I need to provide references in the future, would you be willing to act as one for me?

The second step comes when a prospective employer is actually asking you for references. When they do, you should respond as such:

> I have some people in mind, but before I give you their contact details, I'd like to contact them first to let them know you'll be calling.

You then call the people you intend to use as references and say something like this:

> Hey X, how have you been? I'm calling because I have applied for a new job at Company X and they're asking for references. You told me in the past that you were willing to act as one if I needed one, is that still the case?

If the answer is 'yes', you then ask them what the best time would be for them to be contacted. If the answer is 'no', your answer should be along the lines of *I'm sorry to hear that, thanks for your time, have a good day.*

### Secondly, when an employer asks for references, make sure you understand what references they are looking for.

Some employers are just looking for character references, in which case a family member or personal friend will do. Others are looking to talk to previous managers, to see how you were seen as an employee. Most of the time, they simply want to talk to someone who has experience working with you, in which case coworkers tend to be ideal. When a prospective employer asks you for references, ask for an example of the type of reference they are looking for.

In rare cases, prospective employers will even look for reference letters. These are fairly standardized formal letters, wherein a previous employer or mentor endorses you. These are especially common in the world of Academia, but in some countries they are also in widespread use on the general job market.